# How the move semantic work for make_unique?

Tags: unique-ptr, move-semantics

In the code:

```
accounts.push_back(make_unique<Checking_Account>("James",1000));
```

I know this is an unamed temporary `Checking_Account` object and it will move to a vector, but how the 'move' work? I assume the `Checking_Account` class does not have a 'move' constructor. The push_back method will call a copy constructor but `make_unique` is a unique pointer,so it not allow to copy or assign.

The temporary `Checking_Account` object is R-value reference will call a move constructor, but if I haven't defined a move constructor in any class, the code still run correctly. In my understanding, maybe a move constructor is already defined in the smart pointer class, or compiler will do copy elison which is that the compiler will do move constructor for us, but we will not see this? I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can format your question, your code and add tags for what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `make_unique` will `new` a `Checking_Account` on the heap using the `Checking_Account` constructor that best matches `Checking_Account("James", 1000)`.  Once the `Checking_Account` is on the heap, it need never be moved or copied.

A `unique_ptr` will point to the `Checking_Account` on the heap, and when the `unique_ptr` needs to move, it will simply pass that pointer to `Checking_Account` along to the next `unique_ptr`, while the original `unique_ptr` will set its pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: But without smart pointer std::move() method,how the unamed temporary object which is Chencking_Account move into vector.Because if Chencking_Account move either call move constructor or std::move() method. In this case, no class defined move constructor and I am not use  std::move() method.

Comment: `vector` moves the `unique_ptr< Checking_Account >`.  Not the `Checking_Account`.

Comment: that means if we have `vector` we do not need supply move constructor `vector` will do move for us? because I work on the other class. `vec.push_back(Move{10});` Move class is simple class and have copy constructor.When I execute `vec.push_back(Move{10});` It will call copy constructor. If `vector` can move object why compiler call copy constructor in this case?

Comment: In your question `vector<unique_ptr<Checking_Account>>` is implied, and that type is assumed in my answer.  `unique_ptr` supplies the move constructor that `vector<unique_ptr<Checking_Account>>` uses.

Comment: I know your means.Thanks.Howard